# how to check which PHP version use magento 1.6 or magento 1.7?

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-1.6

I want to check which PHP version magento 1.6 or magento 1.7 is using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At **`index.php of magento application`**,magento check php version.

For **`1.7 & 1.6,php`** version must be  [upper 5.2](https://github.com/amacgregor/magento-1.7.0.2/blob/master/index.php#L27).

```
if (version_compare(phpversion(), '5.2.0', '<')===true) {
......
    exit;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just create `info.php` file at magento root folder and add bellow code in file

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

**OR**

```
<?php echo phpversion(); ?>
```

After run this file in your browser like `http://example.com/info.php`